# Parse.com retrieve entire array android

Tags: android, arrays, parse-platform

I'm trying to retrieve an entire array that is stored in parse. I know how to retrieve int, strings but I dont know how to retrieve an array. I've used .get() but i dont know how to do it. Do I have to create an ArrayList? A List ?

```
//Inside the query
ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>;
list=object.get("array");
```

If you can provide an example please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what getJSONArray() is for.

For example:

```
 ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>;
 list=object.getJSONArray("arrayName");
```

[DOCS](http://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html)

Comment: RTFM is not an answer I want to see. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM Please use an example if possible and I will remove downvote.

Comment: Okay I added an example. Thanks for keeping me in line! SO is better for it.

Comment: Ok, I can't assign a JSONArray to an arraylist... this doesn't compile.

Answer (score 4):

You could use:

```
list.addAll(object.getList("array"));
```

The [API Reference](http://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/) provided by Parse is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

// In ParseQuery //
list = (ArrayList<String>)object.get("ColumnName");
```

I hope this helps